# Simple page fade in

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used a small section of code I have found on here before to fade in an entire page. The code I used was,

SCRIPT

```
<!-- ꜜꜜ page load ꜜꜜ -->
 <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#p-load').fadeIn();
    });
 </script>
```

CSS

```
#p-load {
display: none;
}
```

The problem I am having is that the script is not appears as if it never runs. I have an additional script following this p-load could that have something to do with it?

I'm still learning when it comes to scripts and I still get confused. I know that script runs in order on the page so I have positioned the p-load script above the second script on the page. Here it appears as if the script fails to run.

However when I position the script just below the body tag it appears as if the script does execute however. it just jumps the fade and shows all the content. Thanks for your help in advance.

CODE AS IT STANDS (16:06)

```
            <!-- ꜜꜜ css styles ꜜꜜ -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/division.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navigation.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/library.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/accordion.css"/>

        <!--[if lte IE 8]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie.css"> <![endif]-->


        <!-- ꜜꜜ scripts ꜜꜜ -->           
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#p-load').hide().fadeIn("slow");
        });
        </script> 

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/anim.js"></script>




</head>
<!-- ꜜꜜ end page head ꜜꜜ -->

    <!-- ꜜꜜ page body start ꜜꜜ -->
    <body> 
    <div id="p-load">
```

etc...

The script is executing and running on other elements, as such, I set it to fade out delayed it by 3 seconds and applied it to the footer. the footer faded out after 3 seconds on page load. Why it isnt fading the entire page in beats me... :/

THIS WORKS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#p-load').hide().delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
        });
        </script>
```

I have no idea why the delay triggers the animation now, but it does. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?  Is jQuery loaded before you get to this point?

Comment: Jquery is loaded yes, and im getting no errors as I can see.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4L2Aj/

Comment: @Uday Hiwarale That is what it should be doing except its not fading its just showing the content.

Comment: [`$('#p-load').fadeIn(10000);` __try with high time value in.......FIDDLE ms__](http://jsfiddle.net/4L2Aj/1/)

Comment: Yes, I use an example I had help with. Here is the basics of the script i have implimented with a few size and behaviour changes Ie retracting boxes when another opens. http://jsfiddle.net/BeU3U/6/

Comment: Here is the better one: http://jsfiddle.net/4L2Aj/4/

Comment: Ive lost all content now after that change. two ticks.

Comment: it is correct. please insert your complete code. problem maybe in other place of your code

Comment: @Morteza I have added the code as it stands in my document.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't see it because it fades in too fast. Try with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#p-load').fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

You can specify a duration for fadeIn, "slow", "fast" or a number. "slow" corresponds to 600 milliseconds. I can see the element fading in with duration=5000.

From http://api.jquery.com/fadein/:

> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower
>   animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be
>   supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds,
>   respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration
>   parameter is omitted, the default duration of  400 milliseconds is
>   used.

Comment: Still no luck, The content just violently loads theres no transition what so ever...

Comment: Try 3000ms or 5000ms. Does it get any better?

Comment: I have tried up to 10000 I get absolutly nothing. Just abrupt and immeadiate loading of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Remove display:none style attribute, and use jquery hide instead. So:

```
 <script> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#p-load').hide().fadeIn();
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Still no luck, it just loads it straight in. I dont think it is running the script.

Comment: If you want the whole page to load, you can try running the jquery function above on 'body' instead of '#p-load'. Only other thing I can think of is that something in scripts/anim.js is causing a conflict. I would try commenting that out as everything else looks right.

Comment: Have tried the function on body and commented out the Anim.js. still got no response. I have no errors in the console coming from the p-load script and have tried all varieties of the options given here.... :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#p-load').fadeIn(10000);
    });
 </script>
```

It provides duration of 10sec(10000 m.sec)

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4L2Aj/1/)

Comment: No I do want a fade the slide functions are for the content boxes on the page. Im trying to fade the entire page.